# Частный случай вывода дерева, если левое или правое поддерево пусты

Tags: delphi, pascal

```
procedure vivodtree1(var foutx: text; an: Pelem; n: integer);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  if not (isemptytree1(an)) then begin
    if not (isemptytree1(moverighttree1(an))) then vivodtree1(foutx, moverighttree1(an), n + 1);
    for i := 1 to n do write(foutx, '    '); 
    write(foutx, takeinfotree1(an)); 
    writeln(foutx);
    if not (isemptytree1(movelefttree1(an))) then vivodtree1(foutx, movelefttree1(an), n + 1); 
  end;
end;
```

Данный код красиво выводит дерево горизонтально (корень слева). Но если после  корня будет сразу же пустая ветка, то он чуток криво выведет корень. Можете помочь с исправлением, понимаю что тут должно быть не сложно, но у меня не получается

Вот пример вывода

```
    A
                E
            D
        B
            C
```

Как видите правого поддерева нет и корень сдвинут наверх

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы дерево выглядело вот так

```
            D    E
    A    B
            C
```

придется довольно сильно модифицировать алгоритм.

Сейчас у вас всего 2 ветки выполнения: нет поддеревьев (isemptytree1) или есть.

Придется добавить еще две: Есть только левое поддерево и есть только правое поддерево.

При этом придется добавить еще и промежуточный буфер, где будет сохраняться строка (четыре пробела)+'A' пока выводится правое поддерево элемента 'B' или (двенадцать пробелов)+'D' до вывода поддерева 'E' (которое будет пустым, но на момент прохода через 'D' мы еще этого не знаем).